# How to set UIButton which has title and an image to change the width, according to localisation

Tags: ios, swift, localization, uibutton, storyboard

I have following button configured.

[image]

and this is how I configured it. it works fine with English.

[image]

**I have setup localisation with my app and when new text load to button it looks like below**

[image]

> Note : I have setup `fixed width` constraint using autolayout for the `button` and `relation` to
>   `Greater than or equal`.

how to fix this. hope your help with this.

Comment: How are you adding that image? Show the storyboard or code implementation.

Comment: @Frankenstein I'm adding it `select the button -> attributes inspector -> go to button section in attributes inspector -> Image (I set it here) `

Comment: The seems to be due to setting a constant image inset of `100`. You could calculate the width of the text and change the inset accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Handling Insets for having button and image displayed together is a pain to adjust. A more common approach would be:

1. Create a custom view
2. Add an image and label giving appropriate constraints within the custom view
3. Put a button on top with clear background color so as to make it transparent.

All the three views can should be children of the custom view.
Now using this custom view, you have the flexibility to adjust it as per your needs.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by adding a new `UIImageView` as a subview to the super-view of the `UIButton` and set the `image`. Add the constraints leading(to the trailing of `UIButton`), centreY(to centerY of UIButton), `height and width`(constant you like) constraint to the `UIButton` that you already have. And add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and set the action provided for `UIButton`.

Comment: you can also just remove the user interaction instead of creating an UITapGestureRecognizer